# Groupby, sort and join

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data:

[image]

What I want to do is group this data by name, sort by number and join by the `inter_type` column.

So I want to have this kind of output:

[image]

I don't know how to do it.
I know how to join them by group, but how to sort them? I have no idea how to implement here sort_values()?

```
df.groupby(['name'])['inter_type'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sort_value` in the beginning on the `number` column. Also I modified your code to use `agg` with `','.join` without `lambda` directly, it's more efficient and also it's shorter.

Code:

```
df.sort_values('number').groupby('name')['inter_type'].agg(','.join)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please provide your dataframes as text, but something like this should work:

```
(df.sort_values(by='number')
   .groupby('name')
   ['inter_type'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
)
```